Django admin static files won't load
I'm trying to figure out why my Django admin static files are not loading.

I initiated my django project with:
django-admin startproject project_name .

My Base dir is BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
'django.contrib.staticfiles', is in INSTALLED_APPS
And my static files config:
if DEVELOPMENT_MODE is True:
    STATIC_URL = 'static/'
    STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
    MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

And I ran python3 manage.py collectstatic
What am I doing wrong?

You configured your static files to only work in development?
